# C# how to make this code more compact (If,else if,else)

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm first year student and we are asked to do assigment,I wonder is there any other way to check user input so I would not have to do all the if's and else's after each input or is there any way to loop it and save 6 different answers or something like that.....

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //var
        string s0, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5; //subejects
        string g0, g1, g2, g3, g4, g5;//grades

        //input grades/subject
        Console.Write("Enter Subject 1  : ");
        s0 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter Grade 1  : ");
        g0 = Console.ReadLine();
        g0 = g0.ToUpperInvariant();
        if (g0 == "H1")
            g0 = "100";
        else if (g0 == "H2")
            g0 = "88";
        else if (g0 == "H3")
            g0 = "77";
        else if (g0 == "H4")
            g0 = "66";
        else if (g0 == "H5" || g0 == "O1")
            g0 = "56";
        else if (g0 == "H6" || g0 == "O2")
            g0 = "46";
        else if (g0 == "H7" || g0 == "O3")
            g0 = "37";
        else if (g0 == "H8")
            g0 = "0";
        else if (g0 == "O4")
            g0 = "28";
        else if (g0 == "O5")
            g0 = "20";
        else if (g0 == "O6")
            g0 = "12";
        else if (g0 == "O7" || g0 == "O8")
            g0 = "0";
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong Grade Format!");

        Console.Write("\nEnter Subject 2 : ");
        s1 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter Grade 2  : ");
        g1 = Console.ReadLine();
        g1 = g1.ToUpperInvariant();

        Console.Write("\nEnter Subject 3 : ");
        s2 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter Grade 3  : ");
        g2 = Console.ReadLine();
        g2 = g2.ToUpperInvariant();

        Console.Write("\nEnter Subject 4 : ");
        s3 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter Grade 4  : ");
        g3 = Console.ReadLine();
        g3 = g3.ToUpperInvariant();

        Console.Write("\nEnter Subject 5 : ");
        s4 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter Grade 5  : ");
        g4 = Console.ReadLine();
        g4 = g4.ToUpperInvariant();

        Console.Write("\nEnter Subject 6 : ");
        s5 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter Grade 6  : ");
        g5 = Console.ReadLine();
        g5 = g5.ToUpperInvariant();

        Console.Clear();

        //collect information into array
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            string[] subjects = { s0, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5 };
            string[] grades = { g0, g1, g2, g3, g4, g5 };

            Console.WriteLine("{0,15}:{1,-15}", subjects[i],grades[i]);//output
        }
    }
}
```

Please don't be mad if im asking stupidly easy question but all I can find in web is much more advanced ways of doing it....Thanks.

Comment: You could use a `Dictionary<string,string>` to map the input strings to the output strings. Then you'd just initialise the dictionary in one place.

Comment: Also could use a method `GetSubjectAndGrade(int num)` that returned a `Tuple<string,string>` or something similar

Comment: Hi there, 
i would suggest you put your strings into an enum... g0 == "H1" is realy bad if you need to change it. Then I would wrap this code into a function. Your Console.Write() Calls you could do in an Loop - assigning values to an Array  g[]. Best Regard and good look with your studies

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest initialising a dictionary to do the lookup like so:

```
var lookup = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    ["H1"] = "100",
    ["H2"] = "88",
    ["H3"] = "77"
    // Etc.
};
```

Then look up the strings as follows:

```
g0 = g0.ToUpperInvariant();

if (!lookup.TryGetValue(g0, out g0))
    Console.WriteLine("Wrong Grade Format!");
```

Comment: If he's a first year student, it will be difficult to know what a dictionary is and how to use it.

Comment: @driconmax Hmm well they aren't that hard to use, compared to things like Quicksort algorithms which 1st year CS degree students tend to be learning!

Comment: You learn about dictionaries in the first year of any good CS degree, usually very early first year also...

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Any idea why dictionary won't work on visual studio 2013?

Comment: @EduardsRatniks What version of .Net are you targeting?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `switch`

```
switch(g0){
    case "H1":
        g0 = 100;
        break;
    case "H2":
        g0 = 88;
        break;
    case "H3":
        g0 = 73;
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Wrong Grade Format!");
        break;
}
```

The **switch** is like your **if-else** code internally. In the parameter you put the var to check and then you check each **case** with the value `case "H3"` is the same as `if(g0 == "H3")`. After the `:` and before the `break;` you put the code you want to do if that condition is **true**. If **none** of the conditions are **true**, the **switch** goes to `default:` and execute that code.

Comment: There is no benefit from this approach.

Comment: Less code.... Check the question _I wonder is there any other way to check user input so I would not have to do all the if's and else's after each input?_ And this _I'm first year student_ He just ask for another approach.

Comment: but expanding the switch to fit all his cases would literally be more lines of code

Comment: He is learning.... he just want another approach guys, he is not an ultimate software developer that want super less code to make his server runs faster.

Comment: He want to learn a way to write less if statements, putting a switch and multiple cases doesn't differ from his initial approach. Your code is valid and working, but does not make the situation better.

Comment: How many characters does he write for each `else if`? more that 30... With switch? Less than 30.......

Comment: Actually mybirthname is kinda right,but thanks for answer driconmax

Comment: Friend of mine from year 3 did this in 60lines and mine is 220 if i use all the if's and elses for each input so it would be nice to get it done in like 100-150 lines

Answer (score 0):

judging from your problem, you're somewhat looking for patterns within your input to shorten your conditions. If so, that might be a little bit rough since you really need to interpret every input the user might type and do so with conditions no matter how long.

But despite that, I've attempted to indeed shorten the conditions through the use of patterns I've analyzed based from your code snippet and user input.

This is as far as I can give you for code snippet:

```
var totalGrade0 = 100;
if (g0.Contains("H")) {
    var gradeVal = Convert.ToInt32(g0.Replace("H", ""));
    var initDeductionSet = 12;
    g0 = totalGrade0.ToString();
    if (gradeVal == 2) {
        g0 = (totalGrade0 - initDeductionSet).ToString();
    }
    if (gradeVal >= 4 && gradeVal <= 6) {
        g0 = (totalGrade0 - (10 * (gradeVal - 2)) + initDeductionSet).ToString();
    }
    if (gradeVal == 7) {
        g0 = (totalGrade0 - 63).ToString();
    }

}
```

I noticed that the input is using H1, H2, H3 to define grade codes and give respective grades based from the code. And also, grades were deducted the higher code is given(e.g. H7. Though I didn't included those O1, O2 in my code snippet. Just to give you an idea). Using the integer value from the grade code to my advantage, I was able to see a pattern and use it to automate the deduction process a little bit, effectively reducing the conditions. This pattern is noticeable from H4-H6 where they deduct the grade by 10. Other than that, I don't see anything that might reduce the condition further. Perhaps if you could see some more patterns which are noticeable in the grade code system, you might be able to reduce it a few notches.

The key here is to parse the grade code the users inputted(H1, H2, etc.) and extract the integer value in the code.

If you're looking for a cleaner approach of if-else condition, you might try to use

> Dictionary / Hash tables

or

> switch-case

approach in which you haven't encountered yet I believe. But know that these approach won't shorten your conditions. But they will further make your code readable.